# Bulk update *all* comments of posts but reject cancelled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Post has_many :comments
Comment belongs_to :post
```

I want to bulk update (approve) all comments of posts **that are not `cancelled`**. If there is a cancelled comment selected, display the notification else approve comments.

```
 def make_comments_approved
    comment_ids = params[:comment_ids]

    if comment_ids
      posts = Post.includes(:comments).
        where(comments: { id: comment_ids.keys })

      comments = posts.comments

      cancelled_comments = posts.
        where(comments: { status: :cancelled }).comments

      comments_to_update = comments - cancelled_comments

      if cancelled_comments.any?
        flash[:error] = "Cannot approve cancelled comments: #{cancelled_comments.pluck(:number)}"
      else
        approve_comments(comments_to_update)
        flash[:notice] =
          "#{pluralize(comments.count, 'comment')} successfully approved"
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Select comments to update'
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end

private

  def approve_comments(comments)
    # approve here
  end
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO.  I rolled back your edit, since it removed all of the question's content.  If you were attempting to delete your question, there should be a link labeled "delete" that you can use for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) for bulk update. For example:

```
comments.update_all(approved: true)
```

However, be cautious as it does not trigger validations or callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `comment_ids` with you do following

```
cancelled_comment = Comment.where(id: comment_ids.keys, status: :cancelled)
if cancelled_comment.count > 0
  flash[:error] = "Cannot approve cancelled comments: #{cancelled_comments.pluck(:number)}"
else
  comments = Comment.where(id: comment_ids.keys).update_all()
  flash[:notice] = "#{pluralize(comments.count, 'comment')} successfully approved"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you  are using the ***[search-logic](https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic)*** gem, you can do the following (Syntax is of Rails 2)

```
Comment.status_ne("cancelled").update_all(:approved => true)
```